# jquery slot machine effect without using gif file for animation

Tags: jquery, animation, slot

i was wondering if its possible to make slot animation effect with separated png files, any file will be symbols and after specific time cycle finishes for example after 2 seconds of spinning ? some guy has made a slot machine with jquery allready http://eyecon.ro/slotmachine/ but he uses gif file for animation.

Answer (score 4):

hi I don't know if you still need this, but maybe someone else can use it.
I am currently working on a better version of the slot machine mentioned above.
I will provide a download for the entire project when I'm done.

DEMO: http://slot.pixelass.com
...until there is no download link provided the live-demo can change daily or even hourly.
I am trying to keep the live demo as up-to-date to my dev version as possible.

**Features:**

- casino style slot machine
- Drag-handle
- "real" spinning wheels
- game over mode
- wait to play mode
- win mode